# LTSpice light bulb nonlinear current

Tags: ltspice, non-linear

I'm in a lab and for some reason I cannot replicate my results on LTSpice.

I have gathered data from an experiment where I built the circuit shown in Figure 1. I then took that data, plotted it in Excel and found the polynomial trend line, see Figure 2. However when I try to replicate this experiment in LTSpice, the plot does not match, see Figure 3. I believe my circuit is wrong, but I'm not sure what to change. Any suggestions?

[image: circuit built in lab]

*Figure 1: Circuit built in the lab*

---

[image: Recorded values of the ammeter and voltmeter. Data was plotted and given a polynomial trend line]

*Figure 2: Recorded values of the ammeter and voltmeter plotted showing polynomial trend line*

---

[image: ltspice circuit and incorrect plot]

*Figure 3: LTSpice circuit and incorrect plot*

Comment: You need to tweak your polynomial and nobody is going to do that except you.

Comment: I've ran the same data through matlab and received the same polynomial but I was mainly worried about the circuit. Thanks Andy!

Comment: One thing I noticed is that the current source is upside down. This is a "reverse light bulb" that recharges the battery when you power it.

Comment: I tried flipping the current source to see what it would change but it still gives me the same plot, thanks for the suggestion though user 253751!

Answer (score 3):

Your curve-fit coefficients are off. Not by a huge amount, but enough to change the curve shape. I get (for a least-square error fit):

```
-0.000172167
0.002980111
-0.01877186
0.071220342
0.012035623
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: @sam It might not matter that much in this case, but for polynomials you can get a speed increase in behavioural expressions by using [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).

Comment: Yes, use Horner's method. There is NO reason ever to not use it for polynomial evaluation.